# How do I find a value in a parent key of a specific child in a JSON data set with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

How do I find a value in a parent key of a specific child in a JSON data set?
My JSON data looks something like this:

```
DATA = {
    "result":"Ok",
    "data":[{
        "orderNumber":"Order1",
        "anyKey":"something else",
        "samples":[{
            "sampleNumber":"sample1",
            "anyOtherKey":"something",
            "item123":"abc 123"
        },{
            "sampleNumber":"sample2",
            "anyOtherKey":"something",
            "item123":"def 123"
        }],
        "tests":[{
            "testNumber":"DP2200200-01",
            "testTypeName":"testtype1"
        }]
    },{
        "orderNumber":"Order2",
        "anyKey":"something",
        "samples":[{
            "sampleNumber":"sample2",
            "anyKey":"something",
        }],
        "tests":[{
            "testNumber":"test2",
            "testTypeName":"testtype2"
        }]
    },{
        "orderNumber":"Order3",
        "anyKey":"something",
        "samples":[{
            "sampleNumber":"sample1",
            "anyOtherKey":"something",
            "item123":"xyz 123"
        }]
    }
]}
```

I need a way to search for string (like `abc`) inside `item123` and return the *OrderNumber* belonging to it. So far I did look it up by

```
  let keyword = "abc"
  let mydata = DATA.data.find(order => order.samples.find(sam => sam.item123.includes(keyword)));
  if ( typeof mydata == 'undefined') {
    document.getElementById("orderNumber").innerHTML = "nothing found :-(";
  } else {
    var myOutput = mydata ["orderNumber"];
    document.getElementById("orderNumber").innerHTML = myOutput ;
  }
```

This works fine as long as the child has the `item123`, so it works for *Order1* but fails for *Order3*, because *Order2* does not have the `item123`. However some sets don't have this property.

Another drawback is that it only finds the first occurrence. How can I find all occurrences and return the associated *sampleNumber* as well?

Comment: `DATA = {` means that you're dealing with JavaScript objects. Not JSOn

Comment: *"How can I find all occurrences and return the associated sampleNumber as well?"* As what, an array containing objects with two properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to filter out the objects

```
const filteredData = DATA.data.filter(d => d.samples.find(s => s?.item123?.includes('abc')));
```

You can then extract the value you need. Here i am extracting orderNumber.

```
const orderNumbers = filteredData.map(fd => fd.orderNumber);
```

You can even use flatMap instead of filter and map to filter and extract in the same loop.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me a lot. The ? was the main trick!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find all occurrences and return the associated sampleNumber as well?

I assume that means you want an array containing (say) objects with those two properties.

You just need nested loops and optional chaining:

```
const results = [];
for (const element of DATA.data) {
    for (const {item123, sampleNumber} of element.samples) {
        if (item123?.includes(keyword)) {
        //         ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− optional chaining
            results.push({item123, sampleNumber});
        }
    }
}
```

If you can't use optional chaining in your environment yet, you can just do a truthiness test:

```
        if (item123 && item123.includes(keyword)) {
```

Live example:

```js
const DATA = {
    "result":"Ok",
    "data":[{
        "orderNumber":"Order1",
        "anyKey":"something else",
        "samples":[{
            "sampleNumber":"sample1",
            "anyOtherKey":"something",
            "item123":"abc 123"
        },{
            "sampleNumber":"sample2",
            "anyOtherKey":"something",
            "item123":"def 123"
        }],
        "tests":[{
            "testNumber":"DP2200200-01",
            "testTypeName":"testtype1"
        }]
    },{
        "orderNumber":"Order2",
        "anyKey":"something",
        "samples":[{
            "sampleNumber":"sample2",
            "anyKey":"something",
        }],
        "tests":[{
            "testNumber":"test2",
            "testTypeName":"testtype2"
        }]
    },{
        "orderNumber":"Order3",
        "anyKey":"something",
        "samples":[{
            "sampleNumber":"sample1",
            "anyOtherKey":"something",
            "item123":"abc 123"
        }]
    }
]};
const keyword = "abc";

const results = [];
for (const element of DATA.data) {
    for (const {item123, sampleNumber} of element.samples) {
        if (item123?.includes(keyword)) {
            results.push({item123, sampleNumber});
        }
    }
}
console.log(results);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

*(Note that I added the keyword to a second element in there so you could see all of them being found.)*

You can also do it with `map` and `flat` (though not, sadly, `flatMap` as we need a depth greater than 1):

```
const results = DATA.data.map(element =>
    element.samples.map(({item123, sampleNumber}) =>
        item123?.includes(keyword) ? {item123, sampleNumber} : []
    )
).flat(Infinity);
```

...but I wouldn't. Harder to read, harder to debug, and involves creating unnecessary temporary arrays. Still, some folks like that kind of thing, so...

Live example:

```js
const DATA = {
    "result":"Ok",
    "data":[{
        "orderNumber":"Order1",
        "anyKey":"something else",
        "samples":[{
            "sampleNumber":"sample1",
            "anyOtherKey":"something",
            "item123":"abc 123"
        },{
            "sampleNumber":"sample2",
            "anyOtherKey":"something",
            "item123":"def 123"
        }],
        "tests":[{
            "testNumber":"DP2200200-01",
            "testTypeName":"testtype1"
        }]
    },{
        "orderNumber":"Order2",
        "anyKey":"something",
        "samples":[{
            "sampleNumber":"sample2",
            "anyKey":"something",
        }],
        "tests":[{
            "testNumber":"test2",
            "testTypeName":"testtype2"
        }]
    },{
        "orderNumber":"Order3",
        "anyKey":"something",
        "samples":[{
            "sampleNumber":"sample1",
            "anyOtherKey":"something",
            "item123":"abc 123"
        }]
    }
]};
const keyword = "abc";

const results = DATA.data.map(element =>
    element.samples.map(({item123, sampleNumber}) =>
        item123?.includes(keyword) ? {item123, sampleNumber} : []
    )
).flat(Infinity);
console.log(results);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```